# Is it possible to get XAML at runtime?

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to get the state of the XAML of a "live" usercontrol? By live I meant the current usercontrol shown on the screen.

Note: I am not talking about XamlReader.Load

I want the live usercontrol shown on the screen. Eg. When usercontrol is loaded suppose it has white background. Then some storyboard runs and the current color of background is green. I want to get this "current" XAML.

Comment: Do dev tools like [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/) fit? Or do you need this to be done in your program's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you. You need to implement yourself as the XamlWriter is not available in Silverlight.

http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/